# Slope/Intercept ratio with Purrr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, lm

I'm looking to print a one way view for the ratio between the slope and the intercept.

so far I've got:

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map(coefficients) %>% map_dbl("(Intercept)")

mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map(coefficients) %>% map_dbl("wt")
```

This works and prints the intercept and slope as required but i cant seem to do any calculations on either.

I've tried the following to get the ratio between the two.

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map(coefficients) %>% map_dbl("wt")/map_dbl("(Intercept)")

mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map(coefficients) %>% map_dbl("wt"/"(Intercept)")

mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map(coefficients) %>% map_dbl(map_dbl("wt")/map_dbl("(Intercept)"))
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

subset the current element `.`/`.x` using names then create a division formula using `~`

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.[["coefficients"]][["wt"]]/.[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]]) #%>%
  #enframe(name = "cyl", value = "ratio") #produces output as a data.frame

          4           6           8 
-0.14270545 -0.09786058 -0.09185668
```

to make your approach works we can use `{}`

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg~wt, data =.)) %>% 
  map(coefficients) %>% {map_dbl(.,"wt")/map_dbl(.,"(Intercept)")}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way without purrr, but with broom:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
do(tidy(lm(mpg~wt, data =.))) %>% 
summarize(ratio=estimate[2]/estimate[1])
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl   ratio
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4 -0.143 
2     6 -0.0979
3     8 -0.0919
```